# Adding a rank column to a data table after sorting it

Tags: c#

i am trying to add a new column to a data table that is the rank.  For that I want to loop through each row after sorting and then assign a rank to each row starting at 1.

Below is my code.  However The rank is getting assigned to the row before the sort it looks like.
So my rank calculation is not doing what its supposed to do.  Is it possible to add a rank this way?

```
protected void bindGridView(GridView gv)
{
    using(DataTable dt = getData())
    {
        DataColumn dc_Total = new DataColumn("Total");
        DataColumn dc_Rank = new DataColumn("Rank");            
        dt.Columns.Add(dc_Total);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc_Rank);
        dc_Rank.SetOrdinal(1);
        dc_Total.SetOrdinal(2);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dr["Total"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr["A_B_PERC"].ToString()) + Convert.ToDouble(dr["C_PERC"].ToString());
        }
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Total";
        int rank = 1;
        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dr["Rank"] = rank;
            rank++;
        }
        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Below is the result I'm getting:
[image]

What I really want is:
[image]

Comment: You are sorting a *view* of the DataTable.

Comment: Why do you need the DataBind()?  It may be the source of the issue.

Comment: @jdweng don't i have to call Databind after setting the datasource? if i don't have that nothing will display in the gridview

Comment: Is is a GridView or a Data Grid View?  For DGV :  To get data to display set DataSource to null.          gv.DataSource = null; gv.DataSource = dt;  For GridView : Use only DataBind().

Comment: @jdweng this is a grid view.

Comment: I was able to fix it though finally.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem with the code below:

```
protected void bindGridView(GridView gv)
{
    using(DataTable dt = getData())
    {
        DataColumn dc_Total = new DataColumn("Total");
        DataColumn dc_Rank = new DataColumn("Rank");            
        dt.Columns.Add(dc_Total);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc_Rank);
        dc_Rank.SetOrdinal(1);
        dc_Total.SetOrdinal(2);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dr["Total"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr["A_B_PERC"].ToString()) + Convert.ToDouble(dr["C_PERC"].ToString());
        }
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Total";
        using(DataView dv = dt.DefaultView)
        {
            int rank = 1;
            foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
            {
                drv["Rank"] = rank;
                rank++;
            }
            gv.DataSource = dv;
            gv.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps if anyone else is having similar issue.